# Polygon intersection using QGIS virtual layers

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sqlite, unique-id, virtual-layer

I'm trying to intersect polygon geometries in QGIS by using a virtual layer:

```
SELECT
    sbqry.rowid AS gid,
    sbqry.geom
FROM
    (SELECT
        ST_Intersection(land_parcels.geometry, flood_zone.geometry) AS geom
    FROM land_parcels, flood_zone
    WHERE ST_Intersects(land_parcels.geometry, flood_zone.geometry) AND NOT ST_Touches(land_parcels.geometry, flood_zone.geometry))
    AS sbqry;
```

Unfortunately, `sbqry.rowid AS gid` returns NULL instead of auto-incrementing values.

[image]
[image]

Does anybody know how to create an unique identifier column named 'gid'? As far as I know virtual layers are based on SQLite/Spatialite.

Comment: What data type are you using for the virtual layer?

Comment: The input layers are .shp files, the output geometry type is 'polygon'.

Comment: I didn't know you could run spatial functions (ST_*) on shapefiles! That's great!!!

Comment: have you tried removing sbqry from 'SELECT rowid as gid'... I found another post with such an example.

Comment: 'rowid AS gid' works with simple SELECT statements like creating a buffer but not with a subquery.

Comment: Just checking, but what do you want to use gid for? I get that it has to be unique, but does it have to be an auto-incrementing number?

Comment: ...just need to create an unique key!

Comment: If that is so important for you, create another query that wrap the one you did.

Comment: @eclipsed_by_the_moon did you see this link?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110805/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-autoincrementing-primary-key-field-to-an-existing-spati

Answer (score 3):

In PostGIS, if you just want the row number you can do this:

```
SELECT
    row_number() over () as gid,
    sbqry.geom
FROM
    (SELECT
        ST_Intersection(land_parcels.geometry, flood_zone.geometry) AS geom
    FROM land_parcels, flood_zone
    WHERE ST_Intersects(land_parcels.geometry, flood_zone.geometry) AND NOT ST_Touches(land_parcels.geometry, flood_zone.geometry))
    AS sbqry;
```

Comment: 'row_number() over()' seems to work in PostGIS but not in SpatiaLite (QGIS virtual layers).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  f.rowid AS gid, f.geom
FROM
(SELECT sbqry.geom
FROM (SELECT ST_Intersection(land_parcels.geometry, flood_zone.geometry) AS geom FROM land_parcels, flood_zone 
WHERE ST_Intersects(land_parcels.geometry, flood_zone.geometry) AND NOT ST_Touches(land_parcels.geometry, flood_zone.geometry)) AS sbqry) as f
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the query returns NULL values only.