# Merging infomation from multiple layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers

I am currently looking at a city map with property boundaries.

I have three layers of information, one is a polygon map showing the boundaries, one is a polygon map showing overlay information, and one is a point map with addresses.

Is it possible to filter the information using data from different layers?

i.e. show sites over 1000m2 (using the property boundaries layer) that are also contained within a certain overlay area (from the overlay layer).

I've looked into '*merge vector layers*' and '*join attributes by location*' tools but couldn't get either to work.

Comment: You can only merge vectors that are of the same type. But if you can use `geopandas`, you can easily get the result you want by applying a condition on the different vectors you have.

Answer (score 1):

The long way would be to  'join attributes by location', you shoul use it twice to get both poylgon attributes to points layer and then use 'Select features by Expression' on new points layer.

Quicker way is to use query: Layer > Create layer > New virtual layer
.Then compose querry to your needs. For example something like:

`SELECT * from "addresses" WHERE st_intersects("addresses"."geom", "propertes"."geom") AND Area("propertes"."geom") > 1000`

Either way you decide to go, there is enough answered questions to help you go along:
[Joining 2 layers by location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308428/joining-2-layers-by-location-doesnt-join-desired-fields-from-attributes-tables/308431#308431) 
[Polygon intersection using QGIS virtual layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200458/polygon-intersection-using-qgis-virtual-layers)